# “She´s happy” vs “She's happy” vs “She’s happy” vs ...?

Tags: apostrophe, computing, typography, diacritics, handwriting

I’ve always wondered what the correct apostrophe is when using contractions. Should I use *She´s happy* or *She's happy*?

1. English**´**s a universal language.
2. English**'**s a universal language.

Why do a lot of people use **´** for this, as though it were *caf**é** au lait*? Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"She's happy" uses unicode character U+0027, which is an *apostrophe*.

"She´s happy" uses unicode character U+00B4, which is an *acute accent*.

The first is correct, the second is wrong.

There are other alternatives to U+0027 as an apostrophe:-

There is unicode character, U+02BC [᾿], which is the *modifier letter apostrophe* and that could also be used appropriately.

It should be noted that the Unicode committee ([controversially](https://tedclancy.wordpress.com/2015/06/03/which-unicode-character-should-represent-the-english-apostrophe-and-why-the-unicode-committee-is-very-wrong/)) recommend using character U+2019 [’] for an apostrophe (which is the *right single quotation mark*).

The reason that using the acute accent and right single quotation mark characters is a problem, is that machine parsing of the text (such as autoformatting) can misinterpret the intended character and produce erroneous output. (We see something similar here when people use the grave accent (U+0060 [`]) along with the acute accent as quotation marks and it renders the word between in code markup.)

Comment: When handwriting or painting (e.g. a sign), you can make an apostrophe any shape you like; it doesn't have to be a dot with a tail. When I write with a pen, my apostrophes look like short acute accents.

Comment: This isn't about the shape, on a computer that's determined by the choice of font, it's about the character that's being used. Using an acute accent when you should be using an apostrophe is just wrong.

Comment: @KillingTime You might also demonstrate ’ (U+2019, ASCII 146) which happens to be correctly formed in the font "Georgia" used here. And maybe even U+2032 (prime, ′) so that this might become a canonical answer.